# How to keep a dynamic value history to rows with timestamp VBA/Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in VBA and I'm suffering to make a script to work properly.
Target:
I have on A10 cell a dynamic number, every few days or hours its value changing by a formula.
I want to keep all the values that this cell ever had...
I couldn't find any way to do it with formula, so I tried with VBA and I wrote the following script:

```
    Dim xVal As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static xCount As Integer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("A10").Address Then
        Range("D2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = xVal
        Range("C2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Now()
        xCount = xCount + 1
    Else
        If xVal <> Range("A10").Value Then
         Range("D2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = xVal
         Range("C2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Now()
        xCount = xCount + 1
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    xVal = Range("A10").Value
End Sub
```

I have two issues with the specific script:

- Although I have saved it as .xlsm everytime that I open the workbook the script overwrites the values beginning of C2, so I lose the previous values...
- I do not know why but though the script works smoothly is keeping the previous value that the cell A10 had and not the current one.

Could you please give me your help?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean A10 rather than C10? When you re-open the file `xCount` will be zero. How exactly are you doing this - it seems to rely on you selecting a cell?

Comment: Yes, you are right, A10 is the cell which includes the dynamic value. Yes, that is the problem, if I close the excel file the next time will replace the cell c2 because xCount is zero... Is there any way in order to keep the variable updated with the last value before excel was closed?

Comment: Either store the value in a cell or use approach like answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try only this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCount As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    xCount = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    If Target.Address = Range("A10").Address Then
        Range("D2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Range("A10").Value
        Range("C2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Now()
    Else
        If xVal <> Range("A10").Value Then
         Range("D2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Range("A10").Value
         Range("C2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Now()
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

When I put function =NOW() in "A10" then sometimes =NOW() in "A10" which was copied to "D" showed a second earlier time than the time value in "C" but I guess it is not a problem.

Edit:

```
Option Explicit ' To be sure there are not misspelled variables

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim valueCell As Range
    Dim timeStampCell As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim xVal As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '''''EDIT''''''

    Set targetCell = Range("A10")
    Set timeStampCell = Range("C2")
    Set valueCell = timeStampCell.Offset(0, 1)

    '''''''''''''''

    xCount = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, valueCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1 ' Now it is not checking the third column but the valueCell column

    If Target.Address = targetCell.Address Then
        valueCell.Offset(xCount, 0).value = targetCell.value
        timeStampCell.Offset(xCount, 0).value = Now()
    Else
        If valueCell.Offset(Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, valueCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 2, 0).value <> targetCell.value Then  ' Now duplicates, I forgot I got rid of xVal variable
         valueCell.Offset(xCount, 0).value = targetCell.value
         timeStampCell.Offset(xCount, 0).value = Now()
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use endxlup as if nothing under C2 it will go to the last row in the sheet.

Comment: SJR, right, I forgot about the situation when it is empty :) Thanks, I solved it this way. Maybe not most elegant way.

Comment: Did it with end(xlUp).

Comment: It works and that is fine for me, but do you know why if I change the target column the value is overwritten? I changed the target cell to Z2 for value and Y2 for timestamp and the values don't go in lines... Also, I another issue is if I change a value from another cell in the sheet there is duplicate values from script's cells. If you could advise would be much appreciated!

Comment: There were duplicates because I forgot about xVal. It didn't work when you changed the column probably because I guess you didn't change the column in xCount (Now it is conjugated).

Comment: Perfect! Work like a charm now! I had an issue with the chart but I changed the Now() with Date() and now everything works amazing... Thanks again for your time to make it work properly.